# C++ - Maximize sum of two elements in the array and their indexes

Tags: c++, algorithm

How do I solve following programming riddle in O(N)?

> Array of integers: `Tab[N]` 
>   Find `max(Tab[K] - K + Tab[L] + L)` 
>   where `0 <= K <= L <= N`

The only solution I can come up with is `O(N^2)` where I compare each element and update maximum sum.

```
int curr_max = INTEGER_MIN;
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for(int j = i; j < N; j++){
        curr_max = max(Tab[i]-i + Tab[j] + j,curr_max);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need quadratic algorithm, replace it with two cycles, find maxin-i first, then max+j in second, then sum up them.

Comment: @Manvel thank you for your time, the problem with this approach is that K <= L thus it may be possible with this method that L > K and this does not satisfy requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, a possible way to solve such kind of tasks, due to `K<=L` constraint, is to use pre-calculated running max. (The version below can be optimized, but anyway has `O(N)` time and space complexity.)

```
int t[N+1]; // input

int a[N+1]; // running max t[i]-i, left to right
a[0] = t[0]-0;
for (int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
    a[i] = max(a[i-1], t[i]-i);

int b[N+1]; // running max t[i]+i, right to left
b[N] = t[N]+N;
for (int i = N-1; i >= 0; --i)
    b[i] = max(b[i+1], t[i]+i);

int mx = a[0] + b[0];
for (int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
    mx = max(mx, a[i] + b[i]);
```

**However, in our case**, it can be shown that if `K: Tab[K]-K -> max` and `L: Tab[K]+K -> max` then `K<=L`. In other words, if `L` and `K` are indices of the two maxima respectively, the property `L<=K` holds. Therefore, the naïve approach should work too:

```
int K = 0, L = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= N; ++i) {
    if (t[i]-i > t[K]-K)
        K = i;
    if (t[i]+i > t[L]+L)
        L = i;
}
assert(K <= L);
int mx = t[K]-K + t[L]+L;
```

Comment: It's simple you look for k_max first if you find it you can look for l_max from point where you find last k_max. And when you get k_max and l_max it's simple sum of k_max and l_max. Worst scenerio is O(2*n) best is O(n).

Comment: @Logman Oh, the solution might be even simpler. Just one pass, due to the fact that `K<=L` seems to hold _always_ for indices of our maxima. (I did not put the proof, but it does not look complicated.)

Comment: @Logman In big O notation constants does not matter thus O(kn) = O(n)

Comment: @carpenter Yes i know but I want to describe it in fast way and I use the O in an informal way. AlexD best solution ever.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
int L_max = INTEGER_MIN;
int K_max = INTEGER_MIN;

for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
  K_max = max(Tab[i] -i, K_max);
  L_max = max(Tab[i] +i, L_max);
}
curr_max = K_max + L_max;
```

Note that it does not validate K <= L, neither does the code in the question.